# loop through nested json objects and display kay/value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json object of which i want to print its `key/value` pair combination. but my object is nested one. so i want to loop through each object and display its key/value pair.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ydzsaot5/

Code:

```
var html='';
var contextObj = {"CategoryID":"1","BillerID":"23","BillerName":"MERCS","RequestType":"QuickPay","AccountNo":"1234567890","Authenticator":"{\"EmailAddress\":\"dfgsdfgsdfg\",\"MobileNumber\":\"65-4576573\",\"ID\":\"4572-4756876-8\"}","Token":"3C639AE65"};

html = getKeyValueJson(contextObj, html);
$('div').html(html);
function getKeyValueJson(obj, html) {
    $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return
        }
        if (typeof value == 'object') {
            getKeyValueJson(value, html);
        }
        else {
            html += '<label>' + key + '</label> :-  <label>' + value + '</label><br>';
        }
    });
    return html;
}
```

I want to print in this way :

```
....
AccountNo :- 1234567890
EmailAddress :- dfgsdfgsdfg
MobileNumber :- 65-4576573
....
Token :- 3C639AE65
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your json and in your code , you just given it as a string

```
"{\"EmailAddress\":\"dfgsdfgsdfg\",\"MobileNumber\":\"65-4576573\",\"ID\":\"4572-4756876-8\"}"
```

change it to

```
{"EmailAddress":"dfgsdfgsdfg","MobileNumber":"65-4576573","ID":"4572-4756876-8"}
```

```js
var html = '';
var contextObj = {
  "CategoryID": "1",
  "BillerID": "23",
  "BillerName": "MERCS",
  "RequestType": "QuickPay",
  "AccountNo": "1234567890",
  "Authenticator": "{\"EmailAddress\":\"dfgsdfgsdfg\",\"MobileNumber\":\"65-4576573\",\"ID\":\"4572-4756876-8\"}",
  "Token": "3C639AE65"
};

html = getKeyValueJson(contextObj, html);
$('div').html(html);

function getKeyValueJson(obj, html) {
  $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    
    value = parseIt(value) || value;
    
    if (value == null) {
      return
    }
    console.log(typeof value);
    if (typeof value == 'object') {
      html += getKeyValueJson(value, html);
    } else {
      html += '<label>' + key + '</label> :-  <label>' + value + '</label><br>';
    }
  });
  return html;
}

function parseIt(str) {
  try { return JSON.parse(str);  } catch(e) { return false; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you work it out without changing `json` object ?

Comment: You can use something like `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @PranavCBalan I just edited the code due to out of curiosity.. Sorry if you feel that my activity is bad.. :\

Comment: @Shaggy Checkout his code and demo now.. A simple error catching technique needs to be implemented with it, since a string that cannot be converted into a JSON will throw a runtime error.